# How to use SugarCRM's local API?

Tags: sugarcrm

they're exposing a REST and SOAP API to access data but none of them seems really fitted to my purpose of inserting lots of data through external RPC calls, which are somehow time-critical (There are a dozen users working the same time on the data).

I only spend a few hours to get an idea how things work in SugarCRM but I figured out its best to place an independent RPC server beside of SugarCRM and then do the processing(huge) part and afterwards storing it into the database, using preferable Sugars own API.

Is there a way to include their core API in order to benefit from their model and persistence API ? 
I'd like to know which files I need to include and how to access the running instance, if there is one.

Its actually quite simple what I am trying to do :

1. Receiving RPC calls
2. Do some matching
3. Update database

You see, there is no GUI part involved which justifies the long way of using modules, etc..

Well, I hope someone knows it. Its seems a pretty big beast to me and I'd love to keep it quick'n dirty.

thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here You find a starting point for your own API [Extending the REST API](http://forums.sugarcrm.com/f6/extending-rest-api-56126/) and here is a overview of what [API versions](http://developers.sugarcrm.com/wordpress/2010/12/21/explaination-of-all-of-the-sugar-web-services-apis-available/) exist.

We are using a time critical custom API to speed up some calls.

Comment: hi, thanks ! this is more about the local API. The RPC stuff is just the gateway to my app. However, I figured out that I can access the entire API by including "entryPoint.php" in my app. Didn't test it yet but it seems creates also the DB object, and a local system user.

Comment: sure you can set up an entry point directly. a custom api like I suggested isn't that hard too. depends on the format in which you want to exchange your data. json together with some tuned methods did the job for us.